# Apache Tomcat 6 and Cpanel Errors

Tags: configuration, tomcat6, cpanel

Using cPanel easyApache I installed Apache Tomcat 5.5.x and attempted to upgrade it to Tomcat 6.x.x

Download and expand Tomcat 6 in /usr/local/jakarta
Changed group owner to Nobody/Tomcat with 0755
Changed tomcat symlink to /usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-6.x.x
Extracted and built the native daemon jsvc
Uncommented and changed /usr/local/jakarta/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>  
<user username="tomcat" password="secret" roles="manager-gui"/>  
</tomcat-users>
```

Copied from 5.5.x to 6.x.x

```
/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/conf/workers.properties  
/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/conf/httpd-jk.conf
```

Installed Servlet from cPanel to my domain:

```
Main -> Account Functions -> Install Servlets
```

Restarted Tomcat using

```
/scripts/restartsrv_tomcat
```

I can browse to the url ie www.tomcat.com:8080 and I see the correct version number.
So in my public_html folder I created a test.jsp. When I visit it I get error:

500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Looking in the logs for apache, I find no errors, there is an error in the mod_jk log:

```
[Tue Jan 25 18:51:40 2012] [21925:47707893800752] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2686): Could not find a worker for worker name=ajp13
```

So checking workers.properties I see it contains:

```
worker.list=wlb,jkstatus
worker.list=ajp13
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13.host=localhost
worker.ajp13.port=8009

worker.wlb.type=lb
worker.wlb.balance_workers=ajp13w
```

Im stumped as to what else is missing that is causing the error I am seeing in the browser, any and all hints and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried only having one **worker.list**, so setting it to something like _worker.list=wlb,jkstatus,ajp13_. I'm having very similar problems myself on this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/355248/ubuntu-apache-railo-pages-never-time-out-or-load

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of your duplicate **worker.list** lines, and also you don't have a worker called **ajp13w** which you're calling as a balance_worker.

```
worker.list=wlb,jkstatus,ajp13
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13.host=localhost
worker.ajp13.port=8009

worker.wlb.type=lb
worker.wlb.balance_workers=ajp13
```